# C# Notification Sending Issue: Notification Sent Only for the Last Account in the List

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing an application in C#, in the wpf framework.
I have a problem with sending notifications to be displayed on the desktop.
I decided to use the 'Notification.Wpf' package to send notifications.

---

```
 public class ToastNotificationSender : IToastNotificationSender
    {

        private readonly NotificationManager _notification;

        public ToastNotificationSender()
        {
            _notification = new NotificationManager();
        }

        public void SendNotification(string title,string message,NotificationType notificationType)
        {
            _notification.Show( title,message,notificationType);
        }
    }
```

An example use of this implementation which works correctly no matter how many times I execute it

```
 private void TestMethod()
    {
        _toastNotificationSender.SendNotification("Test Notification","This is test notification",NotificationType.Success);
    }
```

The problem occurs when I call the ClaimCredits method

**The way the Claim Credits method is called**

```
private void ClaimCredits()
        {
            var accounts = _accountsManager.GetAllAccounts();

            foreach (var account in accounts)  
            {
                _creditClaimer.ClaimCredits(account,_toastNotificationSender);
            }
        }
```

**ClaimCredits method :**

```
public void ClaimCredits(UserAccount account, IToastNotificationSender notificationSender)
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxWaitTime);
            notificationSender?.SendNotification("Login", $"Logging in to {account.Email}", NotificationType.Information);
            LoginModule.Login(_driver, account);
            if (_driver.Url == LoginUrl)
            {
                notificationSender?.SendNotification("Login Failed", $"Failed login for : {account.Email}, check your credentials", NotificationType.Error);
                _logger.Log("Login failed");
                _driver.Quit();
                return;
            }

            _logger.Log("Logged in successfully");

            if (!GoToProfile())
            {

                _logger.Log("Going to profile failed");
                _driver.Quit();
                return;
            }
            _logger.Log("Navigated to profile page");
            if (!ClaimCreditsOnAccount(notificationSender))
            {

                _driver.Quit();
                return;
            }
            _logger.Log($"Claiming credits completed successfully for {account.Email}");
            notificationSender?.SendNotification("Credits Claimed", $"Claiming credits completed successfully for {account.Email}", NotificationType.Success);
            _driver.Quit();

        }
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, the notification is only sent to the last account in the list.

Things I tried that didn't work :

- Remove the IToastNotificationSender parameter, and create a ToastNotificationSender inside the method
- I made sure that IToastNotificationSender is not null

Finally, I would like to emphasize once again that sending notifications in any other place works flawlessly

Thank you for your help. If any information is missing, let me know

Comment: Problem has been sloved. In this case, the solution was to run the _creditClaimer.ClaimCredits() in a new thread